# Header image resize with no theme

Tags: php

I am trying to locate the view.xml file in my magento2 installation.

I have no theme selected (i.e. I have not selected Luma or blank).

I want to resize my header image (height and width) but I cannot find the file location.

I have been using the following link: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-images.html

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

```
Content -> Configuration -> Edit -> Header
```

in the Admin area. This should allow you to edit both Logo Attribute Width and Logo Attribute Height. Another way I'd do it is through CSS but given you have no theme at all I'm not sure if it's possible to reference a CSS file without a theme. Although you could paste your CSS in to the "Scripts and Style Sheets" section on the page I've directed you to. Let me know if if what I've suggested first works

Comment: I think it's hardcoded. I have tried going through the Admin page as you suggest but it has no effect at all (which seems to negate the point of having it in the first instance). I just want to know where the parameters are set.

Comment: Interesting, it works for me, i don't know browser you're using but in the developer tools I'd inspect the element and the ones around it to see if any particular CSS somewhere is telling it be a certain size. It's interesting because I just made mine larger by changing in the admin panel

Comment: I did think it must be something my side otherwise they would not provide the functionality. I have the same issue with the category images too.

Comment: What I would do, personally is first, view page source. See if any unusual scripts are being loaded, also inspect element on the item and just see if anything is restricting size. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks - looks like it is loading a luma front end without my specifying it.